PostgreSQL "Error: could not determine data type of parameter $5"
I'm encountering an issue with my Node.js application when trying to insert data into a PostgreSQL database using the pg module. I have a table named offres with a column date_publication of type DATE. When I attempt to insert data into this table, I'm using the CURRENT_DATE function to automatically insert the current date into the date_publication column.
But when I post my data I receive an "Error: could not determine data type of parameter $5"
this is my current code :
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { titre, description, entreprise, lieu, date_limite, type_contrat, salaire, experience, diplome_requis, competences } = req.body;
        const newPost = await db.query('INSERT INTO public.offres(titre, description, entreprise, lieu, date_publication, date_limite, type_contrat, salaire, experience, diplome_requis, competences, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, CURRENT_DATE, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, NOW(), NOW())',
        [
            titre, 
            description, 
            entreprise, 
            lieu, 
            date_limite, 
            type_contrat, 
            salaire, 
            experience, 
            diplome_requis, 
            competences, 
        ]);
        res.json(newPost.rows[0]);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send('internal server error');
    }
});

I verify If my data-type where correctly set in type date into my psql database and all is good.
So how can I display the current date in date-publication whitout facing this error ?

In your query, replace $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11 with $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10. It corresponds to the position of the param in your Array

$5 is missing in your code
